# Complex integral confirmation

Tags: complex-analysis

Got this question:

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac {1}{(z- \frac{1}{2})^2} dz$$

In the solutions it says it is equal to zero. By CIF, I think it should be equal to $f(\frac{1}{2})2\pi i$, where $f(z) = 1$; so it would be $2\pi i$, but by hand I seem to get $-2\pi i$.

As an aside, these are my workings by hand:

$z = e^{it}, dz = ie^{it} dt$

$$i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac {e^{it}}{e^{2it} - e^{it} + \frac {1}{4}} dt$$
$$=i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-it} - 1 +4e^{it} dt$$
$$= [-e^{-it} -it + 4e^{it}]_0^{2\pi} = -2\pi i$$

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't it have the primitive function *i.e.* $\int()=-\frac{1}{z-1/2}?$

Comment: How did you come up with $e^{-it}-1+4e^{it}$? The problem is here. The other problem is that the integral should be $0$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm an idiot, I split the fraction $e^{it}/e^{2it}$ etc.

Comment: Okay, I see it's $2/(1-2e^{it})$ now to get zero. Why was my idea of using CIF wrong, I'm not too sure what you mean by the primitive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that should be equal to $f'(1/2) 2i\pi$ *not* $f(1/2) 2i\pi$ where $f(z)=1,$ and by [CIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) the integral is zero.

Moreover, the integral has a primitive function *i.e.*

$$\int \frac{1}{(z-1/2)^2}dz=-\frac{1}{z-1/2}+c$$

thus the integral over any loop is zero.

Comment: Thank you, I remember now.